# What is an appropriate training set size for sentiment analysis?

Tags: nlp, scikit-learn

I'm looking to use some tweets about measles/ the mmr vaccine to see how sentiment about vaccination changes over time.  I plan on creating the training set from the corpus of data I currently have (unless someone has a recommendation on where I can get similar data).

I would like to classify a tweet as either: Pro-vaccine, Anti-Vaccine, or Neither (these would be factual tweets about outbreaks).

So the question is: How big is big enough?  I want to avoid problems of overfitting (so I'll do a test train split) but as I include more and more tweets, the number of features needing to be learned increases dramatically.

I was thinking 1000 tweets (333 of each).  Any input is appreciated here, and if you could recommend some resources, that would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

More is *always*  better. 1000 tweets on a 3-way split seems quite ambitious, I would even consider 1000 per class for a 3-way split on tweets quite low. Label as many as you can within a feasible amount of time.

Also, it might be worth taking a cascaded approach (esp. with so little data), i.e. label a set `vaccine` vs `non-vaccine`, and within the `vaccine` subset you'd have a `pro` vs `anti` set.

In my experience trying to model a catch-all "neutral" class, that contains everything that is not explicitly "pro" or "anti" is quite difficult because there is so much noise. Especially with simpler models such as Naive Bayes, I have found the cascaded approach to be working quite well.

Comment: More than 1000 huh? Might not be able to get away with that, but I will do my best.  With respects to the cascading, wouldn't that still mean I would have three groups: vaccine pro, vaccine anti, and non-vaccine?  Maybe I've misunderstood the cascading approach.

Comment: For the cascading, you'd still have 3 groups, but you'd train 2 different classifier on two 2-class problems, rather than a single classifier on a 3-way split. Also, with so little data, Semi-Supervised Learning (e.g. Naive Bayes + Expectation Maximization) and Active Learning can help build a better classifier.